# Quantifying Reliability of Qualitative Testing

Tags: distributions, correlation, multilevel-analysis

If a visual grading system is implemented to calculate the correlation between exterior and interior conditions (i.g., good, medium, bad), and a sample is taken from a known population to test the reliability of the grading system, what is the best distribution and method of analysis for quantifying reliability and the amount of uncertainty with the grading system.

The method is to be used in order to develop way of estimating the interior condition based on the exterior.  The sample size is approximately 15% of the total, from which conditional probabilities of the possible outcomes of each test can be calculated.

I am stuck finding a well fit distribution model and method of analysis.  The sample size cannot be assumed to be completely random, instead it represents a good distribution of exterior conditions.  I understand this complicates the analysis.

Any methods, examples, links to follow to mathematically derive the uncertainty in the conditional probabilities calculated from this method would be appreciated.